# how to get the Knowledge__kav custom fields using the KnowledgeArticleVersion object

Tags: apex, soql, knowledge, articles

I am using the knowledge(`Knowledge__kav`) object with 4-5 custom fields.
For an article having 5 version. How can i query the archived article version with the custom field using `KnowledgeArticleVersion` object.

```
SELECT Id, Title, Revision_Notes__c, Short_description__c 
FROM Knowledge__kav 
WHERE Language= 'en_US' And PublishStatus='online' 
WITH DATA CATEGORY Knowledge_Base_Category__c BELOW Download__c.
```

In the above query `Revision_Notes__c` and `Short_description__c`  are the custom fields.
I needs to get those two fields value using KnowledgeArticleVersion object.

The below is the query which i was tried but getting error

```
SELECT 
Id, KnowledgeArticleId, VersionNumber, FirstPublishedDate, LastPublishedDate, ArchivedDate, KnowledgeArticleId.Revision_Notes__c, KnowledgeArticleId.Short_description__c   
FROM KnowledgeArticleVersion 
WHERE PublishStatus='Archived' AND IsLatestVersion=false AND KnowledgeArticleId='kA01s0000004fMaCAI'
```

Error :

> LastPublishedDate, ArchivedDate,KnowledgeArticleId.Revision_Notes__c
>
> ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:115 Didn't  understand relationship 'KnowledgeArticleId' in field path. If you are
> attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r'
> after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the
> describe call for the appropriate names.

Can some one help me to know how to get the knowledge object custom fields using the `KnowledgeArticleVersion` object.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you found since the question is old, but you just have to remove `KnowledgeArticleId.` in `KnowledgeArticleId.Revision_Notes__c, KnowledgeArticleId.Short_description__c`.

The fields are on the Knowledge article version (Knowledge__kav), not on the Knowledge article (Knowledge__ka). Knowledge articles don't have custom fields.

The data model for Knowledge is described here : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.knowledge_dev.meta/knowledge_dev/knowledge_development_object_model.htm

In addition you can use the [Salesforce Inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-inspector/aodjmnfhjibkcdimpodiifdjnnncaafh) browser plugin to easilly build and check your queries and to view all fields and relationships of all objects.

Answer (score -2):

In Setup->Digital Experiences->Settings enable the "Enable ExperienceBundle Metadata API" checkbox. Then your queries with custom fields will show the correct results. (Custom fields are stored on Knowledge__kav, not KnowledgeArticleVersion FYI)

(I believe this applies for imports/exports with DataLoader also)

Comment: How does enabling experiences to use `ExperienceBundle` help a query on a Knowledge object?